# Visual Studio 2022: Don't show ALL repos in Azure DevOps > Connect to a Project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have connected to Azure DevOps account via Visual Studio, but it loses connection with the repo I was working. Therefore I need to connect to a repo often and VS is not listing all repos most of the time, although it shows connected account.

[image]

Clicking Refresh does sometimes list a few repos, but not all (still it takes several minutes to load the list).

For others, it started working when they Signout and sign in from VS, but not for me.

Any idea why ?
VS version: 2022 Professional

Answer (score 0):

this setting in VS seems to have finally solved it. (default was "Embedded web browser")

[image]